# Javascript - Anonymous Functions

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

```
var add= function(x,y) {
    document.write (x+y +"<br>")
}
add (4,5)
document.write (add(6,7))
```

Output:

```
9  
13  
undefined
```

why the undefined is coming

Comment: <script>
var add= function(x,y) {
  document.write (x+y +"<br>")
}
add (4,5)
document.write (add(6,7))
    </script>

Comment: Output, shows, 9, 13, undefined. why the undefined? TA

Comment: Because `add` has no `return` statement, it implicitly returns `undefined`. So you don't want to `document.write` the result of the function - just calling it is enough. (Although you shouldn't use `document.write` anyway...)

Comment: I used return initially, but to test the execution,. Thanks. So,  does it mean, an anonymous function by default has to return a value, else will get undefined.

Comment: This isn't an anonymous function.  It is referenced by the `add` variable, so that is effectively its name.  And no, a function, be it anonymous or not, is not required to have an explicit return.  It should only explicitly return if it needs to do so.

Comment: also @epascarello is incorrect.  You can have function act on a global variable

Comment: @madhu Any function, whether anonymous or named, returns `undefined` by default if it doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Because your function is returning nothing that's why by default it returns undefined

Comment: so clarify the basic logic, does it mean, that an anonymous function cannot be used without return statement.

Comment: No it means if you do not return something you can not use its output.

Comment: returning a value is optional in the JavaScript functions but if you omitted the return value  keyword then by default it returns undefined as always for the named and anonymous  function

Comment: Thanks for the basic.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
document.write (add(6,7))
```

The .write method is receiving the return of the add method.
add method is not returning anything, so gets undefined (nothing).
So then, is writing undefined.

Comment: This is the reason I was confused about, Thanx for clarifying, and thanx to SO.

Answer (score -1):

Because in the document.write() you ran the function who is already ran when you called it before.
for example this code log undefine:

```
let a;
  document.write(a);
```